# Half of the lifecycle methods of fragment get not called after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm experiencing an strange behavior of Fragment life-cycle each time that i rotate the screen. Only the first half of life-cycle methods are getting called, `onPause`,`onSaveInstanceState`,`onStop`, `onDestroyView`,`onDestroy` and `onDetach`. The other half (onAttach ...-onResume) are not getting called. The Activity associated with the Fragment is calling all its life-cycle methods.
Any help would be highly appreciated because I'm stuck on this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Here the entire code of the Activity and the static nested class where is the Fragment:

```
public class MoviesFeed extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static boolean mTwoPane;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("ACT","onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.themoviedb_main);
        if(findViewById(R.id.detail_activity_container)!=null) {
            //the detail_activity_container will be present only in large-screen
            //Layouts (res/Layout-sw600dp. If this view is present, then the activity
            //should be in two-pane mode
            mTwoPane=true;
            //In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by adding
            // or replacing the detail fragment using a fragment transaction
            DetailActivityFragment detailActivityFragment=new DetailActivityFragment();
           // Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
           // bundle.putBoolean("twopane",mTwoPane);
           // detailActivityFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.detail_activity_container, detailActivityFragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        } else {
            mTwoPane=false;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d("ACT","onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d("ACT","onResume");

        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d("ACT","onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d("ACT","onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        Log.d("ACT","onRestart");
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("ACT","onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.movies_feed_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public static class MoviesFeedFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        private static final int APPROX_FIXED_IMAGE_WIDTH=170;
        private  GridView mGridView;
        private  MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;
        private  ArrayList<Response.Movie> mListMovies=new ArrayList<Response.Movie>();
        private  TimeMeasure mTm;
        private  boolean mFromDetailsActivity =false;
        private  boolean mUserRotation=false;
        private  boolean mFavoritesMode=false;

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            Log.d("FRAG", "onAttach");
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.d("FRAG", "onCreate");
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_moviesfeed, container, false);
            Log.d("FRAG", "onCreateView");

            mGridView= (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), mListMovies);
            mGridView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
            //for tablets specially
//        float scalefactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * APPROX_FIXED_IMAGE_WIDTH;
//        Point size=new Point();
//        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
//        int number=size.x;
//        int columns = (int) ((float) number / (float) scalefactor);
//
//        mGridView.setNumColumns(columns);
            if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                mUserRotation=true;
                ArrayList<Response.Movie> tempList=new ArrayList<Response.Movie>();
                tempList=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("mListMovies");
                mListMovies.clear();
                mListMovies.addAll(tempList);
                mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), mListMovies);
                mGridView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
            }


            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("FRAG", "onActivity");
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            Log.d("FRAG", "onPause");
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            Log.d("FRAG", "onStop");
            super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            Log.d("FRAG", "onSaveInstanceState");
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putParcelableArrayList("mListMovies", mListMovies);
        }


        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            Log.d("FRAG", "onResume");
            super.onResume();
            if (mFromDetailsActivity !=true && mUserRotation!=true) {
                executeCallToMoviesApi();
            } else if(mFromDetailsActivity==true && mFavoritesMode==true) {
                getFavoritesMovies();
            }
            mFromDetailsActivity =false;
            mUserRotation=false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            Log.d("FRAG", "onDestroyView");
            super.onDestroyView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Log.d("FRAG", "onDestroy");
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            Log.d("FRAG", "onDetach");
            super.onDetach();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mTwoPane==true) {
                DetailActivityFragment detailActivityFragment=new DetailActivityFragment();
                Bundle args=new Bundle();
                args.putString("movieId", String.valueOf(mListMovies.get(position).getId()));
                //Response.Movie movie=new Response.Movie();
                //movie.setId(mListMovies.get(position).getId());
                //args.putParcelable("movie",movie);
                args.putBoolean("favoritesMode",mFavoritesMode);
                detailActivityFragment.setArguments(args);
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.detail_activity_container,detailActivityFragment)
                        .commit();


            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("favoritesMode", mFavoritesMode);
                intent.putExtra("movieId", mListMovies.get(position).getId());
                mFromDetailsActivity = true;
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        public void executeCallToMoviesApi(){

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            String orderStr= sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_order_key),
                    getString(R.string.pref_order_default));
            mFavoritesMode=false;
            if (orderStr.equals(getString(R.string.pref_popularity))){
                getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.mainactivity_title_popularity));
                getMoviesByPopularity();

            }
            if (orderStr.equals(getString(R.string.pref_rate))){
                getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.mainactivity_title_rate));
                getMoviesByRate();
            }
            if (orderStr.equals(getString(R.string.pref_favorites))) {
                getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.mainactivity_title_favorites));
                mFavoritesMode=true;
                getFavoritesMovies();
            }
        }

        public void getMoviesByPopularity(){

            ApiClient.MyApi myApi=ApiClient.getMyApiClient();
            myApi.getMoviesByPopularityDesc(AppConstants.API_KEY, callbackResponse());


        }
        public void getMoviesByRate(){
            ApiClient.MyApi myApi=ApiClient.getMyApiClient();
            myApi.getMoviesByAverageRate(AppConstants.API_KEY, callbackResponse());


        }

        private Callback<Response> callbackResponse() {

            return new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Response response, retrofit.client.Response response2) {
                    //    Message.displayToast(MoviesFeed.this, "success");

                    mListMovies.clear();
                    mListMovies.addAll((ArrayList) response.getResults());
                    mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), mListMovies);
                    mGridView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);



                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Log.v("VILLANUEVA", "error:" + error.getMessage().toString());
                    Message.displayToast(getActivity(), "failure" + error.getMessage().toString());
                }
            };

        }

        public void getFavoritesMovies(){
            List<MovieDetail> tempListDetail;
            ArrayList<Response.Movie> tempList=new ArrayList<Response.Movie>();
            SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager=new SharedPreferenceManager(getActivity());
            tempListDetail = sharedPreferenceManager.getFavoritesList();
            Response.Movie tempMovie;
            if (tempListDetail!=null) {
                for (MovieDetail movieDetail : tempListDetail) {
                    tempMovie = new Response.Movie();
                    tempMovie.setId(movieDetail.getId());
                    tempMovie.setPoster_path(movieDetail.getPoster_path());
                    tempList.add(tempMovie);
                }
                mListMovies.clear();
                mListMovies.addAll(tempList);
            }
            mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), mListMovies);
            mGridView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);


        }




    }//MoviesFeedFragment
```

Screenshots, before and after rotation.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Log[image]

Comment: Please add your logs so that we can get a clear picture of what is actually happening.

Comment: I have updated the log.